# Proving cardinality of reals = cardinality of continuous functions < cardinality of all functions

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I am trying to solve:

> Let $F$ denote the set of all functions $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, and let $C \subset F$ denote the subset of all continuous functions. Prove that $|\mathbb{R}| = |C| < |F|$.

The proof I have in mind involves quite a few lemmas, even when taking the Schroeder-Bernstein theorem for granted. I'm going to "sketch it" and take these lemmas for granted. I'm interested mainly in whether the proof outline is correct and whether there is a more elegant solution.

We show $|\mathbb{R}| = |C|$ by using the Schroeder Bernstein. Given $r \in \mathbb{R}$, the assignment $r \mapsto f$, where $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is the constant function $f(x) = r$ gives an injection $\mathbb{R} \hookrightarrow C$. Then, since continuous functions are determined by their values on $\mathbb{Q}$, given $f,g \in C$ for which $f_{\mathbb{Q}} \to g_{\mathbb{Q}}$, we have $f=g$. This gives an embedding $C \hookrightarrow R^{\mathbb{Q}}$. One can then show the following equivalences:
\begin{align*} 
|C| & \leq |\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{Q}}| \\
&  = |\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}| \\
& = |(2^{\mathbb{N}})^{\mathbb{N}}| \\
& = |2^{\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}}| \\
& = |2^{\mathbb{N}}| \\
& = |\mathbb{R}|.
\end{align*}
The first line we already showed. The second follows from:

**Lemma.** For sets $A,B,C$ for which $|A| = |B|$, we have $|C^A| = |C^B|$.

And we of course take $C = \mathbb{R}$, $A = \mathbb{Q}$, $B = \mathbb{N}$.

The third line follows from the fact that $|\mathbb{R}| = |\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})| = |2^{\mathbb{N}}|$.

The fourth line follows from:

**Lemma.** For sets $A,B,C$, $(A^B)^C \cong A^{B \times C}$.

We take $A = \{0,1\}$, $B = C = \mathbb{N}$.

The fourth line follows from the first lemma with $C = \{0,1\}$, $A = \mathbb{N}$, $B = \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$.

The fifth line we already used, and follows by identifying $\mathbb{R}$ with the power set $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$.

By the Schroeder-Bernstein theorem, we conclude $|\mathbb{R}| = |C|$. Now, to show that the cardinality of $F$ is strictly greater, we argue:
\begin{align*}
|C| = |\mathbb{R}| & < |\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})| \\
& = |2^{\mathbb{R}}| \\
& \leq |\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}| \\
& = |F|.
\end{align*}
The first line is Cantor's theorem, which states that for any set $X$, $|X| < |\mathcal{P}(X)|$. The next line follows from the natural bijection between $\mathcal{P}(A)$ and $2^A$ using indicator functions. The next line takes a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \{0,1\}$ and sends it to $f^{\star}: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ where $f^{\star} (x) = f(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ (i.e., it simply "extends" the codomain). The final line is the definition of $F$.

---

How does this proof sketch look?

Comment: Looks good to me

Comment: Your proof sketch looks good to me. Keep in mind that even the simplest proofs will look very complicated if you cite every single lemma used - even solving a 7th-grade inequality for $x$ will look complex if you have to cite a theorem to justify every line. The difference is that you have probably internalised these rules to the extend that you no longer need to explicitly cite them to justify them to yourself, while the rules of cardinal arithmetic are probably relatively new to you.